# defining and running a shell function using python subprocess

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I have a piece of python code that looks as following:

```
import subprocess

function = """my_function () \{
echo "test"
\}

"""
alias = 'alias my-function="my_function"'
command = "my-function"
process = subprocess.Popen([function,alias,command],
         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
         stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
print(stderr.decode())
```

I would like to define `my_function` and call it using the command `my-function`

The abovementioned program prints out `/bin/sh: 3: }: not found`, meaning that it doesn't recognize the supplied closing bracket sign `}`. How can I properly define and call this function in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
import subprocess

function = 'my_function(){ echo test; }'
alias = 'alias myFunc=my_function'
cmd = 'myFunc'

# Make combined set of commands
commands = f'''
{function}
{alias}
{cmd}'''

# Run them
process = subprocess.check_output(commands,shell = True)

print(process)
b'test\n'
```

Comment: Aliases are not normally expanded in noninteractive shells. The alias appears to serve absolutely no useful purpose here anyway. Simply name the function `myFunc` if that's what you want its name to be.

Comment: @triplee I agree - I only kept the alias because OP wanted to use one.